# Integral $\int_{0}^{n^{2}} \lfloor \sqrt{t} \rfloor \rm dt $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

To find the integral $\int_{0}^{n^{2}} \lfloor \sqrt{t} \rfloor \rm dt$ if $n \geq 1$ is an integer and $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function, I began with the observation that
$$\int_{0}^{n^{2}} \lfloor \sqrt{t} \rfloor \rm dt = (2^{2}-1^{2})\cdot 1 + \cdots + \big[ n^{2} - (n-1)^{2} \big]\cdot (n-1).$$
However it seems that this observation may not be sufficiently useful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{n^2}\lfloor \sqrt{t}\rfloor dt=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{(k-1)^2}^{k^2}\lfloor \sqrt{t}\rfloor dt\\=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{(k-1)^2}^{k^2} (k-1)dt=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k-1)(k^2-(k-1)^2)=\sum_{k=1}^n (2k^2-3k+1)\\=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3}-3\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n$$

Comment: Very nice answer! Good to show how we get to the sum.

Answer (score 6):

That's the right starting point,  now just write that out in summation notation.   So we have your integral is equal to $$\sum _{k=1}^{n-1}((k+1)^2-k^2)k$$
Simplifying, we get  $$\sum _{k=1}^{n-1}(2k+1)k=2\sum _{k=1}^{n-1}k^2+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=2\cdot \frac {(n-1)(n)(2n-1)}{6}+\frac {(n-1)(n)}{2} $$
Factoring, we get$$(n-1)(n)\left( \frac {2n-1}{3}+ \frac{ 1}{ 2} \right)$$

Answer (score 4):

If your observation is right, then

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}((k+1)^2-k^2)k&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k^2+2k+1-k^2)k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k^2+k)\\
&=2\frac{n({n-1})(2n-1)}{6}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\\
&=n(n-1)\left(\frac{2n-1}{3}+\frac12\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Oops, wrong upper bound. One sec.

Comment: close, but the bounds are off, the top bound is n-1.  I'm almost finishing up typing about the same thing :.  Also you need to use k and not n as the variable inside the summation.

Comment: @Alan: Yes, I am too used to $n$.